# how to send mail on clssical asp by using the .config file

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have a classic asp project. On this project I need to send mail. I need helping hand to send mail from classical asp by using the bellow .config file information.

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="smtpHost" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <add key="smtpPort" value="587" />
    <add key="emailTo" value="xxx@gmail.com" />
    <add key="emailFrom" value="yyy@gmail.com" />
    <add key="smtpUser" value="smtp.test@nazdaqTechnologies.com" />
    <add key="smtpUserPassword" value="test.smtp" />
    <add key="emailSubject" value="Email Auto Reorder for callback" />
    <add key="smtpDomain" value="" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
```

In asp.net I use bellow syntax to send mail

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.To.Add("luckyperson@online.microsoft.com");
message.Subject = "This is the Subject line";
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("From@online.microsoft.com");
message.Body = "This is the message body";
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("yoursmtphost");
smtp.Send(message);
```

I'm just getting into classical asp, so forgive me if this is a basic question. I need help to send mail by using the .config file information .

**I Just want to be able to send an email from my website to a given email address using my gmail account (smtp server).
I have the following code which others have using successfully, but i get  error**

```
<%
Set objCDOSYSMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objCDOSYSCon = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Configuration")

''# Authenticate if necessary
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "username@googlemail.com"
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "mygmailpassword"

''# Outgoing SMTP server configuration
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 1
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

''# Update the CDOSYS Configuration
Set objCDOSYSMail.Configuration = objCDOSYSCon
objCDOSYSMail.From = "username@googlemail.com" ''# This has to be valid email address on the selected SMTP server
strSubject = "Email test"
strHTML = "This is a test"
objCDOSYSMail.To = "username@hotmail.com"
objCDOSYSMail.Subject = strSubject
objCDOSYSMail.HTMLBody = strHTML
objCDOSYSMail.Send 
%>
```

[image]

This is a discussion on Error: 006~ASP 0177~Server.CreateObject Failed~800401f3 –asp show me the above error . Can any one help please to solve this issue------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Without `Set objCDOSYSMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")`  The asp file was working fine  on my os =win7 and win-server-2003 r2.

Comment: It is irritating to read a question that includes the text "I get an error" but the error itself is not included.  You'd think it would be an obvious piece of information to include yet so many questioners miss out this vital info.  What error do you actually get and if possible identify the line that throw the error???

Comment: Sorry AnthonyWJones to irritating you .I am new in classical asp,it's my first time on classical asp,Forget rest of the syntax after add the syntax=Set Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") ,page show error .My os=win7 and win-server-2003 r2 ,iis7

Comment: Yes but what error is it showing? In IIS manager select you application and open the "Error Pages" feature, cliek "Edit Feature Settings...", from the dialog select "Detailed Errors".  Now try to invoke your page, what error do you see in return page?

Comment: shamim can you please post the error.

Comment: Pasha lmmortals  after configure the error on my iis  get http-500 error message,Thanks AnthonyWJones  help me to configure error page

Comment: Just a guess I see the URL is in localhost on port 8080. By any chance are you running this in Cassini (which is visual studio's internal web server)? or you are running it in IIS. Just wondering? Have a look at this link in regards to why I'm asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453762/debugging-classic-asp-in-visual-studio-2010 . Also look at this link if you are running it in IIS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/261200

Comment: Set objCDOSYSMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message") and Set objCDOSYSCon = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Configuration") .show error “ 006~ASP 0177~Server.CreateObject Failed~800401f3 “

Comment: See my reply in the comments section in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Set objEmail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
objEmail.to = "to_email@gmail.com"
objEmail.From = "your_email@domainname.com"
objEmail.Subject = "Subject"
objEmail.Body = "Email Body"
objEmail.send
Set objEmail = nothing
```

Also look here: http://support.jodohost.com/showthread.php?p=73224

**UPDATE:**

Look here for some asp code from MS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972337.aspx

Comment: Pasha Immortals thanks for reply,i fail to understand the first line,will you please like to explain for me,i want to understand the Server.CreateObject parameter,thanks again for reply

Comment: The code above is VBScript. When doing classic ASP the default language is VBScript, there is also JScript, not sure if there is others, but the above using the "Set objEmail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")" is exactly like you were in c# doing "Object dummyObject= new Object();" in VBScript and older versions of VB, VBA CreateObject is used to create COM objects. In the above sample its "CDONTS.NewMail" (Collaboration Data Object for win NT). You might also want to look at CDOSYS depending on your systems.

Comment: Also look at update I put in in my answer for classic ASP tutorial. It has it there as well (not CDONTS but ADODB.Connection which was the way to connect via ADO to DB's). From what I can remember thats the way we used to do it in classic ASP which is CDNTS and I think later we has to move to CDOSYS. So lookup them up and CDO in general as well.

Comment: thanks Pasha Immortals,if my os=win7 if i use Set objCDOSYSMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objCDOSYSCon = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Configuration")
syntax on my asp page show me error.

Comment: Please can you post your entire page and error produced on page + line number. Apologies in advance I'm not in a place right now to try things out but will tomorrow which is in 12-13hrs. Have a look at what this guy is doing on IIS 7, it could be closely configured to yours. http://forums.iis.net/t/1144383.aspx

Comment: @shamim: First don't use CDONTS as outlined in this answer, its well out of date.

Comment: Set objCDOSYSMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message") and Set objCDOSYSCon = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Configuration") .show error “ 006~ASP 0177~Server.CreateObject Failed~800401f3 “

Comment: Mate if CreateObject fails its usually because it could not instantiate an object of that type, so if what you are saying in the above comment is true then it cannot instansiate "CDO.Message" and "CDO.Configuration". Here is a link to some one try to run it from a 64-bit environment and has the same issue and error as you. The main problem being is that you could be running from a 32-bit pool. Here is the link, see how you go: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/da/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/335044b9-58bc-4782-b848-dc547609bfa9

Answer (score 1):

[How to send an email from one Gmail account to another one using a batch file or script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146705/how-to-send-an-email-from-one-gmail-account-to-another-one-using-a-batch-file-or)

```
Const schema   = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
Const cdoBasic = 1
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2
Dim oMsg, oConf

' E-mail properties
Set oMsg      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
oMsg.From     = "from@gmail.com"  ' or "Sender Name <from@gmail.com>"
oMsg.To       = "to@gmail.com"    ' or "Recipient Name <to@gmail.com>"
oMsg.Subject  = "Subject"
oMsg.TextBody = "Text body"

' GMail SMTP server configuration and authentication info
Set oConf = oMsg.Configuration
oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpserver")       = "smtp.gmail.com"
oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpserverport")   = 465
oConf.Fields(schema & "sendusing")        = cdoSendUsingPort
oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic
oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpusessl")       = True
oConf.Fields(schema & "sendusername")     = "from@gmail.com"
oConf.Fields(schema & "sendpassword")     = "sender_password"
oConf.Fields.Update

oMsg.Send
```